# Algebraic curve with an elementary argument for finiteness of $\mathbb{Q}$-points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there a smooth affine algebraic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ of high genus with a $\mathbb{Q}$-point and an elementary argument for why it has finitely many $\mathbb{Q}$-points?

In [Some forms of odd degree for which the Hasse principle fails](https://msp.org/pjm/1976/67-1/p05.xhtml) there are examples of curves of high genus with points modulo every prime and no $\mathbb{Q}$-points (with an elementary argument) but that's a little different.

Comment: What counts as "elementary"?  If the curve $C$ covers an elliptic curve $E$
then it's enough for $E$ to have finitely many points, and there are examples
of such curves that are elementary enough that Fermat proved it.
For example, $y^{2020} = x^3 - x$ has only the rational points with $y=0$
together with the point at infinity, because that's already true for
$y^2 = x^3 - x$.

Comment: (1) Do you want the curve to be smooth? If not, there are silly tricks you can do where the only rational point is the singularity. (2) I'm pretty sure there are curves of high genus whose Jacobians have Mordell-Weil rank 0 and where this can be proven by 2-descent (say). I believe this argument can be presented in an elementary, though potentially very cumbersome, way.

Comment: Ah, of course Noam's solution of mapping to an elliptic curve is simpler than my idea of using the Jacobian.

Comment: Thanks to the commenters. Your suggestions are helpful. But I also am interested in approaches that don't go into a linear setting (elliptic curve or Jacobian).

Comment: How about Fermat curves $x^n+y^n=1$? It has genus $(n-1)(n-2)/2$ and for many $n$ there are [elementary proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem_for_specific_exponents)

Comment: @Wojowu That does work. A family of examples of unbounded degree would be even cooler (it is not known if there is infinitely many regular primes).

Comment: The $n=4$ case implies all the cases with $4\mid n$, so it already gives an example where the degrees grow without bound.

Comment: @Wojowu You are right. I should have asked for examples that are not all covers of one example (at least not in an obvious way).

Comment: There are genus 2 hyperelliptic curves with rational points and no map to an elliptic curve that can be explicitly computed by using covering techniques (which is quite elementary) and then reducing to the computation of some elliptic curves that can be done in an elementary way.